# Update foreign key values with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys

I'm stuck with updating a table with a value from another table. Lets say I have the following tables:

```
Persons table
PersonId (pk), 
Name, 
StateId (fk)

States table 
StateId (pk), 
Level
```

I display the  Name and it's corresponding Level in two inputs, getting the person with this code:

```js
$sel = "SELECT Name, Level FROM Persons P JOIN States S ON P.StateID = S.StateID WHERE PersonID = :pid";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sel);
$stm->execute(array(":pid" => $_GET['personId'])); // personId coming from calling page
$person = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The person is displayed in following inputs (hidden input with personId not shown)

```html
<input type="text" name="person" value=" <?php echo($person['Name']) ?>">
<input type="text" name="level" value=" <?php echo($person['Level']) ?>">
```

When updating I run the following query

```js
$update = "UPDATE Persons SET Name = :name, Level = :level WHERE PersonID = :pid"; // Level = :level wont work
$stm = $pdo->prepare($update);
$stm->execute(array(':pid'   => $_POST['personId'],
      ':name'  => $_POST['name'], 
      ':level' => $_POST['level']));  // again, not correct
```

`Level = :level` is obviously wrong, I tried to replace it with a result from a `SELECT ...WHERE Level = :level` but with no success. How can I update the foreign key of the Persons table based on the value in the input with name="level"?

Comment: Hi, why do you have your `$update` variable twice in a row? I'm afraid the first one is useless, it'll be overwritten immediately.

Comment: That was one of my (not successfull) attempts solving the problem, I've removed it. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it turned out to be an SQL issue:
I changed the `$update` string  to select the `StateID` where Level = whatever the `<input type="text" name="level"...>` tag contains.

```
$update = "UPDATE Persons SET Name = :name, StateID = (SELECT StateID FROM States WHERE Level = :level) WHERE PersonID = :pid";
```